# How to configure GestureListener.Hold event?

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7

How to configure time interval for Hold event in GestureListener from Silverlight toolkit? Default value is about a second. It's too much for my app and I want to decrease this value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GestureListener is designed to give results consistent with the built-in apps on the phone and hence doesn't have this kind of customization.

For most purposes this should be fine. To tweak this you'd probably have to write your own handler using Silverlight manipulation events. You might want to check in the Toolkit source code if there's anything you can reuse, but I expect it uses XNA TouchPanel API under the hood.